# superclass mismatch for class CommentsController (TypeError), best way to rename?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I ran into some problem tonight while deploying and I'm trying to get this fixed asap

I have no idea why this is happening. Everything works fine locally but not on heroku. I tried all sorts of different fixes after researching but I may have to resort to renaming this class CommentsController completely (hopefully that works). What is the best way to go about that? I'm pretty new to Rails so I need some help on making these changing correctly.

Here's what the CommentsController looks like FYI:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  end

  def show
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(params[:comment])
    @comment.micropost = @post
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render partial: 'shared/_comment_form', locals: { post: @post }
    end
  end
end
```

Comments are associated to each post (users are able to comment on posts). I will post other codes up as well if needed.

Here's the error from heroku logs

```
2013-04-09T05:55:19.454545+00:00 app[web.2]: /app/app/controllers/comments_contr
oller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': superclass mismatch for class CommentsControll
er (TypeError)
```

Routes.db

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :posts, :path => "posts"

  resources :users do
    resources :messages do
      collection do
        post :delete_selected
      end
    end
  end

  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :posts, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',   to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',   to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout',  to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/post',    to: 'static_pages#post'
  match '/post1',   to: 'static_pages#post1'
  match '/faq',     to: 'static_pages#faq'
  match '/review',  to: 'users#review'
  match "/posts/:id/review" => "posts#review"
end
```

When I ran advanced indexed search inside the rails app folder, here were the relevant files that came up

```
- comments_controller.rb
- comments_helper.rb
- comments_helper_spec.rb
- comments_controller_spec.rb
- 3 migration files
- routes.rb (posted above)
- schema.rb (table called "active_admin_comments" and table called "comments')
- post.rb model (has_many :comments)
- user.rb model (has_many :comments)
- comment.rb model
- active_admin.rb in config/initializer (any instance where I find "comments" has been #'ed out")
```

Comment: Do you have `CommentsController` declared in any other files in your app?

Comment: Can you update the question with Routes.

Comment: the only thing I have changed in routes since last (working) deployment is adding this line match `"/posts/:id/review" => "posts#review" `

Comment: I didn't even touch `CommentsController` or declare it anywhere, that's why I'm at a loss on what to do. I tried my best to search but didn't find it anywhere

Comment: can you check CommentsController class found anywhere? please use grep command to find it. ex: grep -n -H -r "Comments" ./

Comment: I updated the question with routes

Comment: @Mohanraj, I use windows and I tried my best to try to find CommentsController, but did not find anything

Comment: Do you use some kind of IDE/editor that has a Project Search feature? We suspect the issue here is that, somehow, the `CommentsController` class has been declared in more than one place (in some file, somewhere)

Comment: Is there a end in the last line of your route file? If not can you add end in the last line of your routes file

Comment: I use Sublime text as my editor... I ran an advanced indexed search inside the rails app folder but didn't really come up with anything. I will post up the search results in the original question. The two gems that I added since last successful deployment are oauth and twitter. I uninstalled both already thinking that would solve it.

Comment: yes, there already was an end in the last line of the route file

Comment: The error's happening on the server right? Can you inspect the files on the deployment server to see if there's somehow a file declaring CommentsController a second place on the server?

Comment: all of my deployments up to this point have worked... and this CommentsController has been there for a while with no errors. I didn't really change that much since last deployment. I just posted up the search results in the original question

Comment: any tips on the original question of renaming the controller across the full app?

Comment: Three things you could try: 1. Ensure that your Gemfile has a specified ruby version at the top: `ruby '1.9.3'` and 2. stop your local server and start it again to replicate the error. 3. Search for ApplicationController globally - I suspect you've redeclared it accidentally.

Comment: I'm trying 1 and 3 right now, but what if the app works fine locally? I can't replicate the error. It only happens after deployment on heroku

Answer (score 9):

I had almost the same issue (server starts correctly, but RSpec fails with the same error). 
In my case, the problem was in ActiveAdmin (0.6.0). Don't know what exactly, maybe something related to namespacing.

Just downgraded to 0.5.0
On that version, I didn't have any problems with CommentsController.

Comment: Because I didn't needed the comments feature on active admin, I added: "config.allow_comments = false" in config/initializers/devise.rb and I was able to continue using ActiveAdmin 0.6.0 with my own CommentsController

Comment: I think you meant config/initializers/active_admin.rb rather than config/initializers/devise.rb

Comment: I still get this issue in 0.6.0 with "config.allow_comments = false" running rspec tests, though it seems to work via the browser. Downgrading to 0.5.1 fixes this.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar conflict with the admin namespace, as I had a `Admin::CommentsController` defined within my app.

Try changing the default namespace of ActiveAdmin to something other than 'admin'

config/initializers/active_admin.rb

```
config.default_namespace = :activeadmin # Default :admin
```

Comment: My problem was having an own namespace "admin" defined. This solved it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming ActiveAdmin has its own CommentsController that comes from another base class. It only affects running tests, so I just changed my routes to:

```
unless Rails.env.test?
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
end
```

This solution works perfectly well unless you want to test against the routes inside ActiveAdmin..

Answer (score 2):

As of Active Admin 0.6.1, you can rename the comments module that Active Admin includes so it doesn't conflict with your own. These are the options:

```
# == Admin Comments
#
# This allows your users to comment on any resource registered with Active Admin.
#
# You can completely disable comments:
# config.allow_comments = false
#
# You can disable the menu item for the comments index page:
# config.show_comments_in_menu = false
#
# You can change the name under which comments are registered:
# config.comments_registration_name = 'AdminComment'
```

Comment: I added '0.6.1' to my Gemfile but it requires me to revert jquery-rails back to a version before 3.0